# Why does this async method still work on UI thread and slow navigation?

Tags: c#, multithreading, mvvm, windows-runtime, async-await

I'm trying to run a possibly long-running async method when a page loads. I'm using MVVM Light with messages, SimpleIOC and navigations along with the AsyncEx library. So I'm using as many asynchronous methodologies as I know.

I have a app bar button, when pressed should take me to the next page (StatsPage). I send a message that's received by the `StatsPageViewModel` that will load the viewmodel data. Here's the code for the RelayCommand bound to that navigation button:

```
private RelayCommand _navigateToStatsCommand;
public RelayCommand NavigateToStatsCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _navigateToStatsCommand
            ?? (_navigateToStatsCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                _simpleNavigationService.Navigate(typeof(StatsPage));
                Messenger.Default.Send(new LoadStatsPageMessage());
            }));
    }
}
```

Here's my relevant code in the `StatsPageViewmodel`:

```
// Register messenger in viewModel constructor
Messenger.Default.Register<LoadStatsPageMessage>(this, LoadViewModel);

// An asynchronous property using the AsyncEx library
public INotifyTaskCompletion<List<ScenarioDataCard>>  ScenarioDataCards { get; private set; }

public void LoadViewModel(LoadStatsPageMessage message)        
{
    ScenarioDataCards = NotifyTaskCompletion.Create(UpdateScenarioCardsAsync());
}

private async Task<List<ScenarioDataCard>>  UpdateScenarioCardsAsync()
{
    var tiles = await _client.GetSyncTable<Tile>().Where(t => t.SubAreaId == _subArea.Id).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    var testSets = await _client.GetSyncTable<TestSet>().ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    var today = DateTimeOffset.Now.Date;
    var scenarioCards = new List<ScenarioDataCard>();

    var totalStopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    totalStopwatch.Start();

    foreach (var scenario in _scenariosList)
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        var closedScenario = scenario;
        var scenarioDataCard = new ScenarioDataCard(closedScenario);

        scenarioDataCard.TotalTilesTested = (from tile in tiles
            join testSet in testSets on tile.Id equals testSet.TileId
            where testSet.FieldTeamNumber == _fieldTeamNumber && testSet.ScenarioId == closedScenario.Id
            select tile).ToList().Count;

        scenarioDataCard.TodayTilesTested = (from tile in tiles
                                             join testSet in testSets on tile.Id equals testSet.TileId
                                             where testSet.FieldTeamNumber == _fieldTeamNumber && testSet.ScenarioId == closedScenario.Id && testSet.CreatedAt > today
                                             select tile).ToList().Count;

        scenarioCards.Add(scenarioDataCard);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine("Processed scenario {0} in  {1}", scenario.Name, stopwatch.Elapsed);

    }

    totalStopwatch.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine("Scenario updates completed. Total time: {0}", totalStopwatch.Elapsed);

    return scenarioCards;
}
```

So I use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to make sure the returned asynchronous operation doesn't return on the UI context. However, what I'm seeing is that when I hit the navigate button, it takes a full 2 seconds to navigate to the page and the `ScenarioDataCards` list is already populated. I have some code in there to time the operation and the `UpdateScenarioCardsAsync()` method takes less than .06 seconds to run. Is that too fast that the UI thread can't update fast enough? I just would like to navigate to the page immediately and then have the viewmodel load the `ScenarioDataCards` once the page has been loaded. I've tried working with code in the `OnLoaded` event in the code behind but that seems to block as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `NotifyTaskCompletion.Create(UpdateScenarioCardsAsync());` do?

Comment: It's from the AsyncEx library and allows for asynchronous properties which ScenarioDataCards is. So it'll return a default value at first, and then notify the UI to update the property when the asynchronous operation is complete. More details can be found here https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx.

Comment: That method will have the penalty of switching back to the UI sync context. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: So should I be using code to dispatch to the UI thread from UpdateScenarioCardsAsync()? I want that method to run as soon as the page is navigated to but not to block the UI thread. Basically, what is the best way to populate ScenarioDataCards after the page has loaded?